# Is it appropriate to make /service classes @RestController's

Tags: spring, rest, jhipster

I understand from documentation the distinction between [entity](http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/) and [service](http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-a-spring-service/) creation.  I'm tempted to simply decorate my services with @RestController/@RequestMapping/@[http-method]Mapping in the same way that /web/rest/resources/* are decorated to expose new rest api methods... maybe using "/api/srv/" to distinguish service-level api resources?  It seems to work... when I do it the decorated service methods show up in swagger, etc.  I guess I'm just looking for a sanity check that I'm not violating framework convention or misunderstanding the intended use of /service classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really comes down to separation of responsibility. You can expose any class as `@RestController` no matter it is real `Controller` or a Service or even a `Dao`.

However, most of the time, we want each layer to do its own thing.

- Controller layer handles the http request/response(request param/body, response code/body etc...) and dispatch to different `Service` layer methods.
- Service layer takes care of real business logic and make calls to the `DAO` layer to retrieve data needed for business logic calculation.
- Dao layer eventually has the responsibility access database with query/hibernate/jpa specifics.

As you can see, each layer is trying to do its own thing and isolate the dependencies from other layers. Like controller layer handles http related stuff so that other layers do not have to carry `Servlet` dependencies. Same thing for DAO, so other layers need not know any detail about data persistence.

As for `swagger`, it just analyze your code and annotations and expose whatever in the controller layer. :)

All in all, IMHO, it is still recommended to annotate your real Controller classes with `@RestController` and let your `Service` handle the real business.